# Ncurses.h ( (.text+0xd): undefined reference to `initscr') visual code Ubuntu

Tags: visual-studio-code, ncurses

I need to know why VS code is not compiling ncurses.h. but it is possible to compile in the terminal ubuntu. this message is appearing on the VS code. (.text+0xd): undefined reference to `initscr'

Comment: It might be compiler option issue. Could you be sure VS Code compile options for ncurses.h library?

Comment: "C_Cpp.default.cppStandard": "c++14",

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem adding "-lncurses"  in the "args" (tasks.json)

```
"args": [
    "-g",
    "${file}",
    "-o",
    "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
    "-lncurses" <--------- add the library ("-lncurses" ) here 
],
```

Answer (score 0):

the code runner extension configuration add -lncurses before -o

"code-runner.executorMap": {
"c": "cd $dir && gcc $fileName -lncurses -o $fileNameWithoutExt  &&    $dir$fileNameWithoutExt "
}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).